# Degree of field extension with arbitrary algebraic elements

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am currently stuck on a problem and I would like a hint as to what direction I should go in.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3-x-1$. I am asked to find the degrees of the extensions $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha +1]$, and $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha^2]$, as well as the minimal polynomials of $\alpha, \alpha+1, \alpha^2$. I know that reducing $x^3-x-1 \equiv 0\mod{2}$ gives us the congruence $-1 \equiv 0\mod{2}$ and thus the polynomial is irreducible making the degree of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]= 3$.

From this I can deduce that $\langle 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 \rangle$ form a basis for the extension, and I can see that both of $\alpha+1, \alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Given that the extension is finite and $\alpha+1, \alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ I know that the degrees of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha +1]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha^2]$ must be $\leq 3$, and since $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$ their degrees must also be greater than $1$.

My current thoughts are that we might have that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha+1]=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ similar to how $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}+1]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}]$, but I don't think that this always holds.

At this point I am currently stuck, and would appreciate any help in the right direction, including how to calculate the minimal polynomial for some arbitrary algebraic element.

Thanks

Comment: Think about this:  Say $\alpha + 1$ were in an intermediate field $K$ with $\mathbb{Q}\subset K \subset\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.  Then $\alpha + 1 = k$ for some $k\in K$.  But then $\alpha = k-1 \in K$, which would mean $\alpha$ lives in a proper subfield of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, so its degree would be less than 3.

Comment: Degrees in towers are multiplicative and $3$ is a prime

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please elaborate with an example

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbb{Q}[\alpha +1] $ is true for any algebraic number $\alpha$, as you can see just by using the definition of the field generated by an algebraic number (the minimal field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and the number). As for $\alpha^2$, a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ has a degree that not only is bounded by $3$ but also must divide $3$, because of what Hagen says. So it is either $1$ or $3$. It can not be $1$ as you know so it has to be $3$, and this implies by the way that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$ generate the same field.

Comment: You can also calculate the minimal polynomial of $\beta = \alpha^2$. The equation you have for $\alpha$ gives you that $\beta$ satisfies: $y^{3/2} - y^{1/2} - 1 = 0$, which gives: $ y \sqrt{y} - \sqrt{y} = 1$. Take $\sqrt{y}$ as a common factor and square both sides: $y (y-1)^2 = 1$ , and from this: $y^3 - 2 y^2 + y - 1 = 0$

Comment: @Luisinho great explanation thank you.